# Como bloquear HotLinks de imagens com aviso?

Tags: htaccess

A pouco tempo vi um site que estava exibindo uma imagem hospedada em outro site, pelo menos tentando.. O que acontece é que no site que estava linkando a imagem alheia passou a aparecer uma nova imagem ao invés da imagem desejada.

A nova imagem consistia em um simples retângulo com a frase indicando que a imagem estava sendo "copiada", observando os fontes do site claramente dava para notar o **HotLink**:

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Meu site já  possui no `.htaccess` o bloqueio para os **HotLinks**:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?nome_do_meu_site.com.br [NC]
```

Mas como adicionar essa funcionalidade mencionada?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ponha isso em seu htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?meusite\.com\.br/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ /imagem/anticopia.jpg [L]
```

Após isso, crie uma imagem com o texto desejado ou o que quiser, e altere essa parte do código com o diretório e nome da imagem

> /imagem/anticopia.jpg

Altere também, é claro, o "meusite.com.br"

Eu utilizo essa ferramenta em meu site e acho muito útil.