# Como eu posso evitar o uso indevido do meu servidor web?

Tags: php, apache, htaccess

exemplo eu tenho o dominio `http://marcaregistradanb.com`

e nesse site eu tenho caminho para 2 arquivos um html e outro jpg

1. `http://marcaregistradanb.com/home/nikobellic/public_html/marcaregistradanb.com/logo_site_rm.jpg`
2. `http://marcaregistradanb.com/home/nikobellic/public_html/marcaregistradanb.com/constitucional.html`

como eu posso eu fazer para que hosts externos nao possam referenciem arquivos no meu servidor principalmente imgens e comsumirem banda do meu servidor

existe alguma solucao para esse caso com php?

Comment: Com PHP tem uma diversidade de maneiras diferentes, com .htaccess já tem resposta aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112384/como-bloquear-hotlinks-de-imagens-com-aviso - lembrando que bloquear mesmo, não tem como, mas checar o referrer ajuda bem. Um cuidado a se tomar é aceitar referrer em branco também, para casos em que o referrer é bloqueado pelo browser. Vale a pena não servir a imagem apenas quando você tem certeza que não é uma requisição legítima (o referrer preenchido E evidentemente diferente do seu domínio)

Comment: sera que tem como eu saber se alguem ta citando um artigo do meu blog em seu site tambem? tipo eu escrevo um artigo no meu site sobre o sao joao, dai alguem decide referenciar o meu artigo no seu site existe essa possibilidade tambem de saber a origm de referencia ?

Comment: e que eu tenho uma hospedagem fulera e nao me fornece os arquivos de log mas eu acho que deve ter como

Comment: Da mesma forma, você pode ver o `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` para saber o link que deu origem à requisição. Notar que a grafia do referrer ao usar nos _headers_ é errada por razões "históricas": `REFERER`