# Bloquear acesso direto a arquivo

Tags: php, htaccess

Preciso bloquear o acesso direto a arquivos em um diretório, por exemplo public_html/repositorio.
Neste pasta (repositorio) contém imagens (jpg), pdfs etc.
Não quero que alguém acesse diretamente essa pasta (listando seu conteúdo) ou acessando diretamente um dos arquivos através do link www.meusite.com.br/repositorio/abc.jpg
Utilizei no arquivo .htaccess o seguinte comando: Options -Indexes. Ele bloqueou a listagem dos arquivo quando eu insiro www.meusite.com.br/repositorio/, porém permite que eu acesse o arquivo diretamente.

IMPORTANTE: já utilizei o comando deny from all no htaccess e ele bloqueou o acesso ao arquivo. Porém quando eu acesso o meu site, a imagem também não abre...

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: O que você precisa fazer é bloquear apenas hotlink para a imagem, ou seja tirando seu site qualquer outro seria bloqueado. e para isso existe essa solução: [Como bloquear HotLinks de imagens com aviso?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112384/como-bloquear-hotlinks-de-imagens-com-aviso)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas não deu certo.
Meu .htacess está assim, o que pode estar errado?
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?peticoes.tecologia\.ws/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ [L]

Veja que http://peticoes.tecnologia.ws/repositorio/imagem_principal/ está bloqueando a listagem, mas http://peticoes.tecnologia.ws/repositorio/imagem_principal/140800001.jpg apresenta a imagem...

Comment: coloca seu código na pergunta, fica melhor para vê